# How do I access a Sitecore item bucket as a path?

Tags: sitecore

I have a folder under a page which has bucketed itesm
I need to access the bucketed item via the path and resolve it to a custom path

For eg:
mysite/home/mypage/data/2019/12/25/04/45/obj1

should be resolved as:
mysite/home/mypage/obj1

And my code should search for the item obj1, get the title, description fields from here and then I use them on my View.

I referred to this article:
http://www.codeflood.net/blog/2013/07/18/item-buckets-and-urls/

and overrode the process method:

```
public class CustomItemResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
      if (Context.Item == null)
      {
        var requestUrl = args.Url.ItemPath; // This always returns /nolayout

        // remove last element from path and see if resulting path
        is a bucket
        var index = requestUrl.LastIndexOf('/');
        if (index > 0) // always 0 and never goes ahead
        {
          ...........
        }
      }
    }
```

}

And then the LinkManagerCode

```
  public class CustomLinkManager : LinkProvider
  {
    public override string GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item,
    UrlOptions options)
    {
       if (BucketManager.IsItemContainedWithinBucket(item))
       {
           var bucketItem = item.GetParentBucketItemOrParent();
           if (bucketItem != null && bucketItem.IsABucket())
           {
               var bucketUrl = base.GetItemUrl(bucketItem, options);
               if (options.AddAspxExtension)
                   bucketUrl = bucketUrl.Replace(".aspx", string.Empty);

               return FileUtil.MakePath(bucketUrl, item.Name) + 
               (options.AddAspxExtension ? ".aspx" : string.Empty);
           }
      }

  return base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
}
```

}

When i run the code, the requestUrl variable in my ItemResolver is always */nolayout*. My bucketed item is a datasource and will never have a layout. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this code update from Mike Reynolds. I hate a link only answer, but there is not a github repo to link to. This code uses search to remove the bucket folders from the url.

NOTE: With this code, you can't have two items with the same item name. Because search would find two items instead of just one.

https://sitecorejunkie.com/2016/05/31/omit-sitecore-bucket-folder-item-names-from-page-item-urls/